# MySQL query with value

Tags: php, mysql

i have 2 table like
1.**post**

```
Id  Title        Date
1   Shaghayegh   2015 
2   Adama        2014 
3   roulett      2013
```

2.**postmeta**

```
id  Post_id   Meta_key  Meta_value  
1     1         app         1
2     1         rec      url-rec1
3     1        Square    url-sq1
4     2         app         0
5     2         rec        NULL
6     2        Square      NuLL
7     3         app         1
8     3         rec      url-rec2
9     3        Square     url-sq2
```

I  need a result with mysql query  something like this on where app=1

```
Post.id Post.Title   App      rec       Square
  1      Shaghayegh   1     url-rec1    url-sq1
  3       roulett     1     url-rec2    url-sq2
```

Is there a way to do that ?

Comment: I'm struggling to understand what you're trying to achieve here. What do the 'App', 'rec' and 'Square' represent? They're not columns in your DB so I'm assuming you want to count records with them?

Comment: actually i need a result where app is '1' when app was 1 i need all meta_key and meta_value for that post

Comment: and also i need a row per post

Answer (score 3):

i found the solution, just use MAX (CASE WHEN...)

```
MAX(CASE WHEN (meta.meta_key = 'square') THEN meta.meta_value ELSE NULL END) AS square
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `MAX (CASE WHEN...)`  for convert value as a coloumn